# variable returning undefined value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a function like this

```
function example(){
var a;
$.ajax({
        url:"www.example.com/function",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result){
        a=result;
            }
    });

alert(a);
}
```

I need the variable outside of ajax function

Here I'm getting result as undefined. How can I get the value there. ?

Comment: set async: false so that you are sure the variable is being set.

Comment: A is for Asynchronous. Read the tutorial on http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/key-concepts/

Comment: @Alepac yeah and forcing the ajax-call to be synchronous means the code is going to executed before the alert code is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wait for the ajax call to return, by specifying `async: false`.

```
function example(){
    var a;
    $.ajax({
        url:"www.example.com/function",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            a=result;
        }
    });
    alert(a);
}
```

Comment: I think you should read a bit about what setting async to true/false actually means. Might help you next time.

Comment: I think async true is better than false.

Comment: Doesn't the choice depend on the requirement?

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = "I am defined";
$.ajax({
        url:"www.example.com/function",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result){
           a=result;
           alert(a);
        }
    });


}
```

a Will be undefined until the `success` call back for the `ajax` is called.

Comment: If you want that way it will be undefined.

Comment: Rajesh is correct, you need to listen to him. Else you need to create a function, and call that function when the "success" callback triggers. However this still wont do exactly what you want.
EDIT: If what you mean is you want to store the data to the variable outside the ajax call to be used at some other time, define the variable before the ajax call.

Comment: I think you should have been more specific with your description of your question. I, as I think with RajeshCP, thought you did not want to make any "big" changes to your code. (see your above comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should return the value in the success function itself

function example(){
var a;
$.ajax({
        url:"www.example.com/function",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result){
           a=result;
           alert(a);
           return a;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a default value for the variable a.

Comment: that too doesnt work.it will always show the intitial value. and not the new one. :(